# Error bars cutting off function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm graphing an exponential function with tikz over plotted points with error bars. The graph of the function seems to be getting cut off by the first error bar.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm,
    height=8cm,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    axis lines=left,
    ymin=-1, ymax=4,
    xmin=0, xmax=34,
    ]
\addplot[color=black]{0.2515*pow(2.718,0.0736*x};
\addplot+[only marks, mark=*, color=black, fill=black, mark options={scale=0.5}, line width=0.5pt, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,] coordinates{
(5,0.4) +- (0.1,1)
(10,0.5) +- (0.1,1)
(15,0.7) +- (0.1,1)
(20,1.02) +- (0.1,1)
(25,1.8) +- (0.1,1)
(30,2.2) +- (0.1,1.17)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'm still a bit new to latex so any help would be helpful.[image]

Comment: Hey, even without the data points and error bars the plot stops at the same point. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Add `domain` for first plot, i.e; `\addplot[color=black,domain=0:30]0.2515*pow(2.718,0.0736*x};`